# MVC Submit button not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, button, submit

The Submit button is not calling the method in controller to save data, It is calling method use to load the page. My Code is as follows. I did try `Html.BeginForm("ServiceEntryRegister","",FormMethod.Post)`

```
public class ServiceEntryRegister
{
    public List<ReceiptHeader> HEADER { get; set; }
    public List<ReceiptDetail> DETAIL { get; set; }
    public ReceiptHeader SingleHEADER { get; set; }
    public ReceiptDetail SingleDETAIL { get; set; }
    public List<Suburb> SUBURB { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class ServiceEntryRegisterController : Controller
{

    private AUTOEntities _er = new AUTOEntities();
    private DateTime _Defaultdate = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/1900 00:00:00");

    public ActionResult Index(DateTime P_ServiceDate , String P_Registraion="x", String P_CustomerName="x")
    {
        var Model = new ServiceEntryRegister();
        if(P_ServiceDate!=null || P_Registraion!=null || P_CustomerName!=null)
        {
        }        
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult CreateNew()
    {
        CreateBagForLists();
        var Model = new ServiceEntryRegister();
        return View(Model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    private ActionResult CreateNew(ServiceEntryRegister RH,String save)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            int x = 0;
            x++;
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

VIEW:

```
@model HIMA_AUTOWORKSHOP.Models.ServiceEntryRegister
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <td>
            <table>
                <th> </th>
                <th></th>
                <tr>
                    <td>Dated </td>
                    <td>Nil</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Owner Name</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.SingleHEADER.OwnerName)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Mobile</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(w => w.SingleHEADER.Mobile, null, new { maxlength = 10, autocomplete = "on", style = "width:245px" })</td>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Save Request" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table> 
        </td>
    </table>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: so whats the behavior?

Comment: it is invoking  public ActionResult CreateNew()
    {
        CreateBagForLists();
        var Model = new ServiceEntryRegister();
        return View(Model);
    }

Comment: you are doing return View() in either cases. Are you sure it is not invoking the post method first and then the parameterless one?

Comment: Yes, It is always calling public ActionResult CreateNew(){....} not the one      private ActionResult CreateNew(ServiceEntryRegister RH)

Comment: oh its private, ok that's why. It cannot be private

Comment: Apart from the `private` methods, you have invalid html (a `<th>` cannot be a child of `<table>` and nested tables are terrible practice, as is using tables for layout (tables are for tabular data)

Answer (score 2):

If the method is private then your post request will never invoke that method. But since you did not mark the parameterless method as HttpGet only that's why it gets invoked instead

Comment: Thanks guys, YES  PRIVATE was the issue. Problem solved